# VBA - call overrdiden function

Tags: vba, overriding

I am trying to extract first 2 characters from a String in VBA, using function Left.

```
Left("qwerty", 3)
```

Normally, this function returns "qwe". The problem is in the same module, there is defined another function Left:

```
Public Function Left(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Value As String)
```

Because this, if I call

```
Left("qwerty", 3)
```

the function will extract the substring from "qwerty" from the beginning until string "3", and will return an empty String.

My question is how can I call the standard Left function, when the second parameter is integer.

Comment: You could try `Worksheetfunction.Left` or `Application.Left` to call the `Left` Excel function, but I totally agree with @QHarr.

Comment: If you cannot rename it, then `Strings.Left` or `Strings.Left$` is an option. `Strings` is a class in VBA library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name your own functions after existing functions so rename your current one. As your function is unlikely to be as optimized as the existing one why not simply use that?

Also, used typed function of

```
Left$(myString,3)
```

when using the in-built functions for strings such as `Left`.

Another way of calling `Left` is with:

```
VBA.Left$
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still calling the "custom" function. I did not name that function, it already exists, and I am not allowed to rename it.

Comment: Well whomever controls the naming conventions should be informed. It is very bad practice for exactly the reasons you are discovering and I have mentioned.

Comment: You may also try VBA.Left

Comment: And why can that function not be removed given it already exists?

Comment: QHarr: I don't know this. No original developer in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Found.
VBA.Left$("qwerty",3)

VBA.Left("qwerty",3) still calls the custom function.